# Add multiple members to Office 365 groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-graph

Currently I am able to add member to the Office 365 groups using the following Graph API.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 30

{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
}
```

But I am able to add only one user per request. Is there any way to add multiple users in a single call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add multiple users, we need to make a separate call each to add them to a group.

However, we can combine these requests together using batching as mentioned below:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

In the body, you can specify the requests somewhat as below:

```
{
      "requests": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref"
          "body": {
              "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
            }
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref"
          "body": {
              "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
            }
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref"
          "body": {
              "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
            }
        }
      ]
}
```

More details - [Multiple requests in one HTTP call using JSON batching](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching)

Test it out in -  [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Currently we can combine maximum 20 individual requests - [JSON Batching limitations](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#json-batching)

Comment: Thank you for your help . I tried it by myself, it is working as expected. In each object of the request the header need to be added as below.

      `{
          "id": "2",
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "groups/{id}/members/$ref",
          "body": {
              "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryObjects/{id}"
            },
            "headers": {
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }`